# Update Value in json string inside table SQL

Tags: c#, sql, json, .net, string

I have a string in sql table,it's a json object.So i need to change some value in that item.

> What i need is when `News Title` is `Local News` then `LOC` should be change to `"X"`

Only 1 Local News value in each string.

### String in Db

```
[{"NewsTitle":"Local News","NewsType":"LHN","ValType":"String","LOC":"N"},{"NewsTitle":"Global News","NewsType":"GHN","ValType":"String","LOC":"D"}]
```

I tried to do using Update Query but i can't get the exact string position in this,Any idea how to try.I have searched the internet and i found some idea using hash table to fullfil this.

Comment: What is your RDBMS? Full name with version.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan SQL Server 2019

Comment: Have a look on this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/json-data-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: @HamletHakobyan Good example.but still not found update the json data using a condition.In my case i need .. If NewsTitle is Local News then need to change the LOC as "X"